Google Apps Script "google.script.run" not working on Safari
I'm using Apps Script in Google Sheets. I open a dialog (which works fine) and then when I click the Go button I expect handleGo to run and display "GO-ing!". It works fine on Chrome, but on Safari (17.4.1) it alerts:

Error: ScriptError: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.

There is no additional information on the error in the Javascript console or in the app script execution log. I have tried disabling cross-origin restrictions as well as disabling prevent cross-site tracking in Safari. I am logged in with the correct google account.
Here's my code:
Code.gs
function openDialog() {
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Dialog.html').setWidth(300).setHeight(150);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Test Dialog');
}

function handleGo() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("GO-ing!")
}

Dialog.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      function go() {
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(function() {
            alert("Function executed successfully");
          })
          .withFailureHandler(function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error);
          })
          .handleGo();
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="go()">Go</button>
  </body>
</html>


I'm afraid that this might be unsolvable from the Google Apps Script user side. Please consider reporting this to Google using the issue tracker. For information about this, please check out https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support/

By the way, the current version of Safari is 17.5. Ref. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-17_5-release-notes Try to get the last version.

This works fine on Safari 17.5
Code.gs
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp
    .getUi()
    .createMenu('Demo')
    .addItem('Show dialog', 'showDialog')
    .addToUi()
}


function showDialog() {
  const dialog = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
  SpreadsheetApp
    .getUi()
    .showModalDialog(dialog, 'A dialog');
}

function doSomething() {
  return 'something';
}

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>Click</button>
    <script>
      document.querySelector('button')
        .addEventListener('click', doSomething)

      function doSomething(){
        google.script
        .run
        .withSuccessHandler(successHandler)
        .withFailureHandler(failureHandler)
        .doSomething();
      } 

      function successHandler(){
        alert('Success')
      }

      function failureHandler(){
        alert('Failure')
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>



Thanks. I upgraded to Safari 17.5 and ran the above. It gives me the 'Failure' alert. And doSomething does not show up in the Executions log.

If I display the error in failureHandler like this:
function failureHandler(e){     alert(\Failure: ${e}`)
}`
The alert shows: "Failure: ScriptError: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

@ScottBrave The error comes from the server. It's very unlikely that it's related to Safari. Maybe related to networking settings aren't the same for Chrome and Safari. Also your location might have an effect on this.
